# Using Scala Separator and iterate the values

Tags: scala

Hi  am new in scala basic

i have a doubt

This is about separator in scala

Here the string separated by **comma**   and the string will separated and print it down

i don'nt know this code is possible for that

```
object SeparatorDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var stmt:String=("a,number,of,words")
    var p=stmt.split(",")
    var x=p.length
    for(i <-0 to x){
      println(p)
     }
   }
}
```

output:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@142c842c
[Ljava.lang.String;@142c842c
[Ljava.lang.String;@142c842c
[Ljava.lang.String;@142c842c
[Ljava.lang.String;@142c842c
```

with regards Mila

Comment: Not sure who and why was it negative voted. Anyone who is new to scala is welcome to ask questions. If question was not having correct details instead of marking -1 better Edit it and mention in comment :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing out the array `p` at each iteration. You want to print out the contents of the array that contains the strings. I simplified it to this version.

```
object SeparatorDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var stmt:String=("a,number,of,words")
    var words=stmt.split(",")
    for(word <- words){
      println(word)
    }
  }
}
```

Even more concise is to chain the splitting and the iteration into one statement:    `stmt.split(",").foreach(println(_))`

Either way gives this output:

```
scala> SeparatorDemo.main(Array())
a
number
of
words
```

Comment: thanx alot.................Brian..

it's my college assignments and my friends are really tough with this..  u really help me...